# Cut is not as expected

Tags: modeling

So, I'm making a building and I'd like to make a molding around it on the top, so I press Ctrl-R to slice it and this is what appears. [image: enter code here]`

---

But instead what I want the slice to look like is like this (the slice is in purple):
[image]

Comment: CTRL + R is a Loop Cut. It's not literally a "cut" but a seam (of sorts). You may need the Knife Tool but i am not well versed with it. Im sure someone will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the knife tool worked perfectly! I just got into an isometric view in one side, turned on the cut through with Z anc used C to fix to an angle, it cut like a charm :D

Comment: One of you please make an answer. It seems that you have found a solution for something others might also appreciate. And it would get this out of the list of unanswered questions. @Dontwalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer added for completeness.]

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> initiates a [loop cut](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html#loop-cut-and-slide) and *a new edge loop intersecting the chosen edge*.

To cut through a number of edges, which are not connected by edge loops, use the **[Knife Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html#knife-tool)**.

1. Go to an orthographic view (front view).
2. Press <kbd>K</kbd> to enter the knife tool, press Z (to enter cut through mode) and C (to constrain the angle). Then draw a poly line with two <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> clicks. Press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> to confirm.

[image]

The options you activate while the tool is selected.

> **Cut through** <kbd>Z</kbd>
> Allow the Cut tool to cut through to obscured faces, instead of only the visible ones.
>
> **Angle constrain** <kbd>C</kbd>
> Constrains the cut to 45 degree increments.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible because the loop cut tool is based on your topology, it basically creates one or more loops inside a loop.

However, what you can do is to use the Knife tool with <kbd>K</kbd>, if you watch the 3D viewport's header you will see the Knife tool's options. including the "cut through" <kbd>Z</kbd> which, once enabled via its shortkey <kbd>Z</kbd>, will allow you to cut a straight line through the mesh. Just set a side/front view and that will do the job.

[image]